# Local Group Policy not applied

Tags: group-policy, wsus

My client cant isnt showing up in the WSUS server.
Could anyone help me thru chat? I would appreciate it a lot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a support hotline, and you haven't explained what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [configure-wsus-to-deploy-updates-using-group-policy](http://www.vkernel.ro/blog/configure-wsus-to-deploy-updates-using-group-policy)

Check the Registry to see it your point to the correct server.
[Registry keys](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-xp/Registry-Keys-Tweaking-Windows-Update-Part1.html)